# Reverse look up while removing duplicates excel

Tags: excel, match, lookup, indexof

What would I add to be able to remove duplicate names from this list?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$D$1:$D$46, LARGE((CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$2:$E$46=TL_Team_Management!$I$4)*ROW(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$1:$E$46), COUNTIF(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$1:$E$46, TL_Team_Management!$I$4)+1-ROW(A1))), "")
```

Comment: Kindly provide more details. And formate code properly

Comment: different teams that can be selected. The Leader is located on the left side however that reference point is at the single cell location "I4" Now on another page I want to return the users that match that TL. However in that data base there are multiple records so the other names need to be voided out some how. 
[link](http://s16.postimg.org/oqvg3ytl1/Capture.png)
_italic_ **bold** `=IFERROR(INDEX(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$D$1:$D$46,LARGE((CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$2:$E$46=TL_Team_Management!$I$4)*ROW(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$1:$E$46),COUNTIF(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!$E$1:$E$46,TL_Team_Management!$I$4)+1-ROW(A1))),"")`

Comment: The image link that you see is the page that this formula is on. As you can see it returns the same users many times. I want this formula or something similar to this that will remove duplicates with out manual labor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first cell (top of the retrieved list) is TL_Team_Management!D$11, then this *array formula* should remove the duplicates from a retrieved list.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!D$1:D$46, MATCH(0, IF(CS_LOOKUP_DATA!E$1:E$46=TL_Team_Management!I$4, COUNTIF(TL_Team_Management!D$10:D10, CS_LOOKUP_DATA!D$1:D$46), 1), 0)), "")
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.

Fill down to TL_Team_Management!D34. This style of formula requires that it reference a cell above itself. It is in this way that it ignores duplicates while avoiding circular references.

Comment: You're a rockstar! Thank so much :)

Comment: Actually It still does the same thing. I tried this right now and I still have the same problem. It shows the name many times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Explain please? I am putting this where I need it to go? and it pulls duplicates

Comment: I had to guess where the formula was intended to go. It worked very well at removing duplicates where I put it.

Comment: D11 through D34. I am sorry I am new to all this. I would appreciate you showing me what you mean. I learn quickly. That where the names will appear and where I want the duplicates to not appear

Comment: I had put the formula in CS_LOOKUP_DATA!AA2. I've adjusted it for TL_Team_Management!D11. Note that it references the cell directly above it and keeps track of what to exclude as a duplicate this way.

Comment: This is amazing. Sorry I really need to work on getting to know all this. Just out of curiosity where did you learn to do all this? I like I said am new to this. I know a lot but still get confused with the array type from time to time. And this worked!

Comment: a) self-taught with help from others b) that's not an array formula; no need for CSE. Just put it in D11 and fill down.

Comment: I know, I was referring to something else in this dashboard. That me as well...self taught. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Could you resign this to work with office 2007. Our work doesn't have 2010 +.  Aggregate doesn't work.

Comment: I've supplied a pre-2010 solution above.

Comment: Hey thanks again. I am going to use that. It works great. I will hit you up if I have additional questions in the making of this dashboard and provide credit to you however I can.

Comment: Since you're so good do you think you could take a look on this page. I had another question and this guys not really understanding me. I will give you cred if you can answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031166/dynamic-list-and-blank-space-filtering