# Dynamic list and blank space filtering

Tags: excel, excel-2007, dynamic-list

I have a list which is a combination of two cells for records. For example something like `A1&B2`. Sometimes this is not filled however. The formula below sees that it has `A1&B2` in the field so regardless it thinks it's fields even though the field would be considered `""`.

```
=OFFSET(CCS_Error_Tracker!$A$5,0,0,COUNTA(CCS_Error_Tracker!$A:$A),1)
```

Is there any way this could be configured truly to look for blank spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
=$A$5:INDEX($A$5:$A$1048576,ROWS($A$5:$A$1048576)-COUNTBLANK($A$5:$A$1048576))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. You're the best. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`counta` would look at if there is anything in the cell, even a formula that returns "0" or "" would fit the criteria as non-blank, depending on what is in your columns you're better off using a `countif` and setting the criteria for the count like anything above 0 or if have text try using an istext result. For eg, `=offset((CCS_Error_Tracker!$a$5,0,0,countif(CCS_Error_Tracker!$A:$A,">0"),1)`

Comment: I want my list to auto expand. which is why I used counta because it count the blank cells. What would be in the field is something like this "42225CWILLIA4" But fields that are blank but still have the formula of B112&C112 to make that might not exist yet if that makes sense. So I dont want the list to go down that far. So that way it saves calulation time. Would this formula do what I am asking? I am not sure if it does?

Comment: I think I get you, you're wanting to produce a list of cells once there is information there, removing all the blanks - but keeping it dynamic so once entries come and go, the list updates?

Comment: I'm just about to head out, so I'll take a stab for you - you'll need to create an array formula that brings out different list items skipping blanks, check out this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$50,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$50<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$50)),ROW(B1))),"")` its explained on this site to help out [link] (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/return-a-list-of-non-blank-cells-from-a-column-of/53b11d24-b31a-47d8-adf1-f8d690e3c930?auth=1)

Comment: correct that way I am not search through A5:A100000 I want it to go A5:A13000 one day and A5:A500 the next if no data is there. So would this formula take care of that when entered in the name manager?

Comment: thanks for trying. That's not what I need though. What I need to do is have a formula that works in name manager. I need a list that will auto expand. The formula that I provided will work but counts as far as my list fills even the cell is technically blank but because it fills down that far it counts it. However it does skip the blank past my 600 cell fill. I was just hoping I could make my formula smarter than that.